# Eclipse NoClassDefFoundError when running Elasticsearch JUnit tests

Tags: eclipse, maven, elasticsearch, junit, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run some Unit Tests written for a Mavenized project in Eclipse.  The tests run perfectly fine from the command line.  They also run perfectly fine if I open up Eclipse and run the tests directly off the POM file (i.e. right click on pom.xml and say run maven tests or whatever).

However, I get the following error when I run the tests as JUnit tests in Eclipse:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$1.run(RandomizedRunner.java:562)
```

I am using Elasticsearch version 2.1.0.  The `elasticsearch-2.1.0-tests.jar` that contains `org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase` is listed as a dependency in pom.xml and all Maven Dependencies show up in my Eclipse project's build path.  I even tried specifically adding the jar to my buildpath and to the run configuration's classpath in Eclipse.  Both do not work.  Cleaning my project via `Project -> Clean...` also does not work.

Comment: Is the `elasticsearch-2.1.0-tests.jar` with `<scope>test</scope>`...?

Comment: @carlspring yes, it is.

Comment: It would really help figure out what you're doing, if you posted your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Do you think this is a pom issue?  I am only running it from Eclipse and not from the pom file.  Unless the pom file is dictating my eclipse project's classpath?  I guess knowing the relationship between the pom file and running a junit test in eclipse would help in diagnosing the issue

Comment: If you want good answers, you need to provide good information. Attach your `pom.xml`; a screenshot of your Eclipse dependencies would also definitely not hurt.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440661/junit-test-not-found-system-property-when-run-from-eclipse